# Calculation for latitude and longitude from start to destination point

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location, android-maps

Hi I am new to android development.

I am on college project its based on location which is need to find list of latitude and longitude in between two points.
     **Given Starting position is 12.990143,80.215784 and destination position is 12.992595,80.217618.**

```
 Over the past days i search the google, i found so many links to find distance between locations and mid point. I cant able to find solution for my problem.

Please suggest some solution for this problem. I am struggling over days to find solution for this.


 Thanks in advance
```

Comment: A Latlngs between two said points? On a straight line?

Comment: @GeetChoubey yes in straight line bro

Comment: check this one : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#travel_modes

Comment: I'm trying to understand what [these people](https://www.freemaptools.com/measure-distance.htm) have did. You also can check it out. Hope it helps. This is their [JS file](https://www.freemaptools.com/script/measure-distance.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `SphericalUtil.interpolate` method from the [Google Maps API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/).

For example you can find a `LatLng` that is at 1/5 of the distance between your starting position and your destination by doing

```
LatLng origin = new LatLng(12.990143,80.215784);
LatLng destination = new LatLng(12.992595,80.217618);
LatLng result = SphericalUtil.interpolate(origin, destination, 0.2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the google Directions api to obtain a full PolyLine of the path. You can objain a JSON object and parse it to obtain locations in the path.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=12.990143,80.215784&destination=12.992595,80.217618&mode=driving

This will return a full JSON result which contains everything you would need to find the whole route to all the points falling on it.

You can look more into it on:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Introduction

Comment: yes i tried this direction api which is return the path of latitude and longitude in road. But i need list of latitude and longitude in straight line and export list location.